# paramiko execute_command() on remote machine

Tags: python-3.x, ssh

I am using paramika to connect to a remote machine and run shell commands using execute_command() provided by paramika. I am able to connect to remote server but unable to read a text file in remote machine and set variables using export.

**Step1**: Read input.txt in remote machine
*below are contents of input.txt* 
username=abc
password=xyz
vault_token=nv.ASDFGHFDDFGE

**Step2**: Run 'source input.txt'
**Step3**: Run 'export TOKEN=${vault_token}'
**Step4**: Run 'echo ${TOKEN}'

Below is my code to run the command.

```
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(command)
    exit_status = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()     
    stdout.channel.set_combine_stderr(True)
    output = stdout.readlines()
    print("output is {}".format(output))
    if exit_status == 0:
        print ("Executed command - {}".format(command))
    else:
        print("Error occured while running command - {} with exit status - {}".format(command, exit_status))

def execute_commands(ssh_client):
    commands = [
        "source /home/input.txt",
        "TOKEN=${vault_token}",
        "export ${TOKEN}",
        "echo ${TOKEN}"
    ]
    
    for command in commands:
        exit_status_of_command = run_command(ssh_client=ssh_client, command=command)
        if(exit_status_of_command == 0):
            continue
        else:
            print("Got exit status of {} for command {}. Hence quitting".format(exit_status_of_command,command))
            break
```

But output of 'echo ${TOKEN}' command is ['\r\n'] and the TOKEN value is not set.
How to set the value to TOKEN properly?